# To Call a File from Azure VM which resides within it using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-vm

How to call a file where the File Path resides in **Azure VM** Using the Powershell (ISE Locally).

Using Powershell ISE with local computer and trying to call a Ps file which is placed in the Azure Vm.

Comment: That depends on what's implied by "calling" a file - is it an executable that you want to run? On the VM or on your client?

Comment: please consider that as an .ps1 file which resides within Azure VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to run an .ps1 file inside the VM, then you can use the PowerShell command `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`. You can create a script in your local machine and put the command that you will execute to run the .ps1 inside the VM to the script. For example:

the script `script.ps1` in your local machine:

```
powershell.exe -f 'C:\script_inside_VM.ps1'    # this is the command that will run inside the VM
```

Use the PowerShell command:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName groupName -VMName vmName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '\path\script.ps1'
```

Comment: Script is within the Azure VM and want to call that File from my local computer PS ISE

Comment: @VengateshKaliraj Of course I know. The local script contains the command you need to run inside the VM to execute the script stored inside your VM. Do you understand it?

Comment: Sorry may be i put it in different way. Script/File contains commands which is in inside Azure Vm and i want to run/call that file from my local computer using PS

Comment: @VengateshKaliraj What do you mean by saying that? What is the thing you don't understand in this answer?

Comment: In simple i want to call a File which is inside the Azure VM From my Local Computer PS

Comment: @VengateshKaliraj Why you don't understand the way. To execute the script inside your VM, you need to run commands inside the VM. All of the commands are contained in the local script and will run inside your VM via the PowerShell command `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`. Take a look at this [article](Invoke-AzVMRunCommand).

Comment: I understand that completely. I just want to know what am asking is not possible..

Comment: I have already tried this cmdlet Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ErrorAction Stop -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Name "xxx" -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ` C:\Users\MyScript.ps1 but just wanted to check any other options through which we can use the script path from the Azure Vm itself since our requirement is in that way..

Comment: Thanks Charles for your time and efforts which was helpful

Comment: @VengateshKaliraj Well, if the answer solves your problem, please accept it.